# How to clear auto-remembered "Cancel" command when adding a large OLE object to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ole

When I execute the `Set Obj =`, Excel opens a PowerPoint file that exist in path (that works). When that file is big, there is a Cancel button available (from Windows/Excel, not from my VBA code). If you click that Cancel button, the next time I run this VBA code it always jumps to the `eImport` label, but only if the path is the same. It looks like the Cancel option remembers the command for the specific object and VBA/Excel remembers that it was once cancelled and do not allow to set it. Is there any way to reset it or make some workaround?

```vb
        If Obj Is Nothing Then
            'Handling fault when pptx import was cancel during loading
            On Error GoTo eImport:
            Set Obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(FileName:= _
                PathName & SelectedDeviceType _
                , Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
            Obj.Name = "ActivDev"
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Else:
        MsgBox "Select device type", vbInformation, "Selection required"
    End If

    Exit Sub

eImport:
    Set Obj = Nothing
    MsgBox "Import was canceled", vbExclamation, "Import"
    Exit Sub
```

I add `On Error label` jump which fixed debbuger issue but object to the same file can not be set till next Excel opening.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try deleting the OLEObject before doing `Set`. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobject.delete

Comment: Obj delating is not allowed before creation it. Checked by : Obj.Delete. Debugger shows that crush is on Set command directly.

Comment: Delete it in your error handling in `eImport`. It looks like *something* is linked when the code goes there.

Comment: I tried in eImport : Obj.Delate / ActiveSheet..OLEObjects("ActivDev").Delete. Result was the same, always crush because obj is not existing. Before GOTO eImport was created VBA crush directly on Set command.

Comment: I mean you should loop first `For each Obj in ActiveSheet.OLEObjects Obj.Delete Next Obj` before trying `Set`

Comment: This case will delate all other ActiveX controls which are located in worksheet (which are completly fine and works) so it is not correct way.  Temporary solution is just to prompt Msgbox with request of restart in case if cancel button was pressed unintentionally.